# QML zoom in on an image with x and y but center it when zooming "out"

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to implement a zoom on an QML Image. I am using a WheelHandler with `targetTransformAroundCursor: true` to use the x and y coordinate in the zoom. But this does not work as intended since the image moves around when you zoom out on different coordinates. When the image is centered in the parent, this works but breaks the x and y calulations in the zoom and it just zooms the uppr left corner.

What do I need to do that the image moved back to the middle when zooming out?

Any ideas are highly appreciated! Thanks.

My code is the following:

```
    Item {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: image.width * image.scale
        height: image.height * image.scale

        Image {
            id: image
            //FIXME: this breaks the x and y zoom. But without centerIn: parent, the image floats around when
            // zooming in and out.
          //  anchors.centerIn: parent
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            asynchronous: true
            clip: true
            source: "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/393010/ss_29cf93db42617dd08ceb0a0bf0a4b62ad12a1cfc.1920x1080.jpg?t=1459456906"
            scale: 0.5
            transformOrigin: Image.Center


            WheelHandler {
                target: image
                acceptedDevices: PointerDevice.Mouse
                orientation: Qt.Vertical

                property: "scale"
                rotationScale: 0.25
                targetTransformAroundCursor: true
            }
            BoundaryRule on scale {
                minimum: 0.3
                maximum: 3
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how i implemented it : you can check out and it works pretty well for me:

```
    Item {
        id: photoFrame
        width: rect.width
        height: rect.height
        clip: true                

        transform: Scale {
            id: scaler
            origin.x: pinchArea.x2
            origin.y: pinchArea.y2
            xScale: pinchArea.scale2
            yScale: pinchArea.scale2
        }

        Image {
            id: imageItem
            focus: true
            anchors.fill: parent 
         source : ""                   

        }

        PinchArea {
            id: pinchArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            property real x1: 0
            property real y1: 0
            property real y2: 0
            property real x2: 0
            property real scale1: 1
            property real scale2: 1
            property real maximumScale: 10
            property real minimumScale: 1                    
    
            onPinchUpdated: {                        
                scale1 = scaler.xScale
                var dz = pinch.scale-pinch.previousScale
                var newZoom = scale1+dz
                if (newZoom <= maximumScale && newZoom >= minimumScale) {
                    scale2 = newZoom
                }
            }                 

            MouseArea {
                id: dragArea
                hoverEnabled: true
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: photoFrame                        
                scrollGestureEnabled: false 
                onWheel: {                           
                    pinchArea.x1 = scaler.origin.x
                    pinchArea.y1 = scaler.origin.y
                    pinchArea.scale1 = scaler.xScale

                    //updating the pinch area x2 and y2 with current mouse position
                    pinchArea.x2 = mouseX
                    pinchArea.y2 = mouseY
            
                    var newZoom
                    if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) {
                        newZoom = pinchArea.scale1+0.2
                        if (newZoom <= pinchArea.maximumScale) {
                            pinchArea.scale2 = newZoom
                        } else {
                            pinchArea.scale2 = pinchArea.maximumScale
                        }
                    } else {
                        newZoom = pinchArea.scale1-0.2
                        if (newZoom >= pinchArea.minimumScale) {
                            pinchArea.scale2 = newZoom
                        } else {
                            pinchArea.scale2 = pinchArea.minimumScale
                        }
                    }
                    photoFrame.x = photoFrame.x + (pinchArea.x1-pinchArea.x2)*(1-pinchArea.scale1)
                    photoFrame.y = photoFrame.y + (pinchArea.y1-pinchArea.y2)*(1-pinchArea.scale1)
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
```